# Default.png image in IOS Development in Flash

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, ios

So for the splash screen at the beginning of an iPhone app, usually a Default.png is created and added to resources folder to add it.

In Flash CS5 IOS development there is no resources folder so I was wondering if anyone had any experience how to get this to work.

No code posted as it's dynamic, so doesn't use code.

Thanks

-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a splash screen by naming an image Default.png. You add this to the packager under "iPhone OS Settings" > "General" > "Included files:"